# Foreach performs reduntant logic

Tags: c#, foreach, keyvaluepair

My two ForEach loops allow access to `errorOrders` (the user's name and their number of errors) and `totalOrders` (the user's name and their number of total orders).

My code constantly loops through these two ForEaches. The 'count' on both `errorOrders` and `totalOrders` is 38 and the program loops through all 38 users just fine. But then it keeps looping through them again and again, re-doing the process it just finished.

How can I loop through the users just once?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> error in errorOrders)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> total in totalOrders)
    {

        errPercentage = ((double)error.Value / (double)total.Value);                        
        Console.WriteLine("Percentage of errors for " + total.Key + ": " + Math.Round(errPercentage, 2) * 100 + "%");
        ordersPerHour = OrdersPerHour(total.Key);
        RandomOrders = RandomSelect(errPercentage, total.Key);

        Console.WriteLine("Number of orders pulled : " + RandomOrders.Rows.Count);
        //Print out orders randomly collected
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomOrders.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RandomOrders.Rows[i]["ControlNumber"]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        //NumOrdersToPull = FindNumOrdersToPull(Math.Round(errPercentage,2), ordersPerHour);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to loop thru totalOrders **for each** error?  Also, based on the description you wrote, it would seem that every order has an error.

Comment: Why are you using nested loops? I would imagine that errorOrders would be smaller than totalOrders and you wouldn't want to loop through totalOrders on each error message.

Comment: You say this loops over users... where?  I don't see anything about users in this code.  Also, what is RandomSelect and RandomOrders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate the loops instead of nesting them. Putting one inside of the other makes the *entire* child loop run *for each* instance of the parent loop. (Hence the name.)

```
// (shared variables here)

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> total in totalOrders)
{
    // Code relevant to all orders here
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> error in errorOrders)
{
    // Code relevant to erroneous orders only here
}
```

If the loops need to share variables, declare these before the first loop.  Variables created inside a loop will be local and stop existing when their loop is finished.

Comment: He uses boths totalOrders and errorOrders in the loop here: errPercentage = ((double)error.Value / (double)total.Value);

Comment: @Tejo, that's true, OP might need to swap the order of the loops.  If totalOrders and errorOrders are both relevant, they'll need to be declared outside of the loops so they're not destroyed when one foreach is finished.

Comment: How would you suggest i get the errPercentage if i have the totalOrders & errorOrders split into two different loops?

Comment: @MaylorTaylor If your totalOrders loop comes before the errorOrders one, you'll need to declare a variable before the first loop to hold the (double)total.Value. By storing it outside the loop, you can still access the variable when you're deep into the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

The second loop will run through once for every total in total orders. If you want them to only go through once each do not nest them. instead have them one after the other.

```
foreach(total in total orders)
{

}
foreach(error in errororders)
{

}
```

You would only need to nest them if they were related and you needed to do the inner loop once for every iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> error in errorOrders)
{
    if (totalOrder.HasKey(error.Key) {
        var total = totalOrders[error.Key];

        errPercentage = ((double)error.Value / (double)total);                        
        Console.WriteLine("Percentage of errors for " + error.Key + ": " + Math.Round(errPercentage, 2) * 100 + "%");
        ordersPerHour = OrdersPerHour(error.Key);
        RandomOrders = RandomSelect(errPercentage, error.Key);


        Console.WriteLine("Number of orders pulled : " + RandomOrders.Rows.Count);
        //Print out orders randomly collected
        for (int i = 0; i < RandomOrders.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(RandomOrders.Rows[i]["ControlNumber"]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        //NumOrdersToPull = FindNumOrdersToPull(Math.Round(errPercentage,2), ordersPerHour);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even just one loop, and then a lookup for the other?  is totalOrders a list of some kind? if you could turn one into a dictionary, you could do something like

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> total in totalOrders)
{
    // do work for each order
    object whatever;
    if (errorOrders.TryGetValue( total.Key, out whatever ))
    {
        // do extra work because this order has an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers helped me reach this conclusion:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> e in errorOrders)
{
    errPercentage = GetErrPercentage(e.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("Percentage of errors for " + e.Key + ": " + Math.Round(errPercentage, 2) * 100 + "%");
    ordersPerHour = OrdersPerHour(e.Key);
    RandomOrders = RandomSelect(errPercentage, e.Key);
}

Console.WriteLine("Number of orders pulled : " + RandomOrders.Rows.Count);
//Print out orders randomly collected
for (int i = 0; i < RandomOrders.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RandomOrders.Rows[i]["ControlNumber"]);
}
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

static double GetErrPercentage(string user)
{
    double errPercentage = 0;
    errPercentage = (double)errorOrders[user]/ (double)totalOrders[user];          
    return errPercentage;
}
```